# UIView animation disables toolbar button touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I'm using the following code to move the users screen when the keyboard is displayed (on iPhone):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-control.frame.origin.y/2,320,480);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Problem is for some reason when this code runs, it disables the toolbar button, so it no longer works. Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks

Edit: I've now discovered that its not the animations causing the button to disable. It's actually the following line:

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-control.frame.origin.y/2,320,480);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this call instead:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

And pass in the option: **UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction**

You can pass in delay 0 and completion nil, and simply place your animation code in the animations block.

Comment: I implemented this using the following code `[UIView animateWithDuration:0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-control.frame.origin.y/2,320,480);
    } completion:nil];` however it still disables the toolbar button. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it took me so long to see it, but I saw that the 3rd and 4th parameters were 320 and 480. I'm assumed this is some sort of width and heigh parameter (I'm working with a 4-inch iPhone which has dimensions 640, 960). After changing these values it works perfectly.

Thanks to those for your assistance.